# unix: move files and keep folder structure

Tags: linux, unix

```
Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 x86_64
```

I have two folders with files with the same structure:

I would like to move all files from FTP_UPD to FTP keeping folder structure.

```
FTP_UPD
├── cat1
│   ├── und3
│   └── und4
└── cat2
    ├── und1
    └── und2

FTP
├── cat1
│   ├── und3
│   └── und4
└── cat2
    ├── und1
    └── und2
```

I tried with

```
rsync -a --progress --remove-source-files FTP_UPD FTP
```

but I get error:

```
rsync: --remove-source-files: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1231) [client=2.6.8]
```

Maybe any other options?
Please help me with this.

Comment: Why don't you use `mv` ? Why `rsync` ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès presumably the destination directories already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`mv FTP_UPD FTP`

This will simply move the folder. You could also call rename instead of move.

If you want to keep the old `FTP_UPD` folder with its contents:

`cp -r FTP_UPD FTP`

`-r` parameter causes recursive copying (copying everything that is inside `FTP_UPD`). This can also be read from `man cp`.

Comment: @user3345547 Did you try my solution yet?